# How to copy value from table in function to variable in class?

Tags: java, arrays, function, copy

```
class Name
{
private char[][] table= new char[9][9];

public  fun()
     {
         char table[][]= {
            {'A','B','C',   'D','E','F',   'G','H','I'},
            {'G','H','I',   'A','B','C',   'D','E','F'},
            {'D','E','F',   'G','H','I',   'A','B','C'},  

            {'I','A','B',   'C','D','E',   'F','G','H'},
            {'F','G','H',   'I','A','B',   'C','D','E'},
            {'C','D','E',   'F','G','H',   'I','A','B'},

            {'H','I','A',   'B','C','D',   'E','F','G'},
            {'E','F','G',   'H','I','A',   'B','C','D'},
            {'B','C','D',   'E','F','G',   'H','I','A'}, };
}
}
```

In class I created table char. I want to fill it in function `fun()`, but when I'm doing this its creating new table and I have to send value from `table[][]` in `fun()` to `table[][]` int class. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> this.table

to use the table of the class.

**Update**: Since you don't know what a constructor and getter and setter methods are, I assume you are making a console java app, in which case, this is the simplest working code I can think of.

> ```
> private static char[][] table;
> ```

```
public static void fun() {
    table = new char[][] {
            {'A','B','C',   'D','E','F',   'G','H','I'},
            {'G','H','I',   'A','B','C',   'D','E','F'},
            {'D','E','F',   'G','H','I',   'A','B','C'},  

            {'I','A','B',   'C','D','E',   'F','G','H'},
            {'F','G','H',   'I','A','B',   'C','D','E'},
            {'C','D','E',   'F','G','H',   'I','A','B'},

            {'H','I','A',   'B','C','D',   'E','F','G'},
            {'E','F','G',   'H','I','A',   'B','C','D'},
            {'B','C','D',   'E','F','G',   'H','I','A'} };
}

public static void printTable() {
    for(int x=0; x<9; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<9; y++) { 
            System.out.print(table[x][y]+ " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working or im doing something wrong. I get error ';' expected or illegal start of expersion.

Comment: Remove the last comma.

Comment: Am i have to write it 2 times?  this.setTable(new char[][] { ......
and whats doing "setTable"?

Comment: No, I created a constructor and getter and setter methods (something you don't know yet). See my edited answer for a simpler version.

Comment: Or not. -.- I don't know where is problem. Next to function fun() i have function printTabel();
for(x=0;x<9;x++)
for(y=0;y<9;y++)
System.out.print(this.table[x][y]+ "  ");
and its printing empty space. Is it problem with static value?

Comment: Don't use 'this.' in a static method. Your printTable method must be static.

Comment: Even if I'm not using this. its the same effect.

Comment: I edited my answer. You should read some tutorials on Java. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Eh... I do not have a lot of problems with Java. Accidentally removed something and i didn't see it. Now its working. Thanks.